# How to stop tor from starting before Vidalia?

Tags: networking, tor

I get these errors trying to run tor with vidalia

```
Apr 19 21:55:15.371 [Notice] Tor v0.2.1.30. This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux i686)
Apr 19 21:55:15.372 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 1.4.13-stable using method epoll. Good.
Apr 19 21:55:15.373 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 19 21:55:15.373 [Warning] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Apr 19 21:55:15.373 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Apr 19 21:55:15.373 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

I don't think `tor` is running. Here is a nmap scan of my localhost

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-04-19 21:59 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
Not shown: 989 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp   open  ipp
3128/tcp  open  squid-http
3306/tcp  open  mysql
9000/tcp  open  cslistener
9050/tcp  open  tor-socks
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

I see `tor-socks` is running here, probably be the cause of the problem. How do I stop this from starting up? I want to use `vidalia` so I can monitor whats going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newer versions of [Tor](https://torproject.org/) have a file `/etc/default/tor.vidalia`. It contains three lines:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/vidalia ]; then
        RUN_DAEMON=yes
fi
```

You can change the option to `no`. This will prevent from starting as daemon. Instead Tor will now start when you start Vidalia.

Answer (score 2):

I think the condition is unnecessary.
If you look in /etc/default/tor the tor.vidalia file is not sourced unless that same test passes.

This snipit solved part of my problem, but not all of them, so, DISCLAIMER: I still don't have a working setup.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Go to Settings > Advanced > Tor Control and checked Use TCP Connection (ControlPort) with the address 127.0.0.1:9051 .

For me worked fine

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was that TOR daemon was already running which Vidalia didnt like.

```
ps aux | grep tor
```

Followed by a

```
sudo service tor stop
```

Or a

```
sudo killall tor
```

Then starting vidalia produced no error.

I think also adding qbi's *tor.vidalia* file to start a daemon also helped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer (found [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/164919/83477) ) can be useful. You'll probably have to start from scratch and download the bundle. It has worked for me. The bundle can be found [**here**](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.