# problem with opening tor in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: tor

This message appears:

```
Jan 31 19:18:38.562 [notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.21-stable using method epoll (with changelist). Good.
Jan 31 19:18:38.562 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 31 19:18:38.562 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Jan 31 19:18:38.562 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

HELP! How do I open Tor?

Comment: Kinda obvious, but did you try to simply reboot ?

Comment: Yes I tried to reboot, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Kill all "tor" processes  :

```
sudo killall tor
```

Then start tor again, and finally, restart privoxy and polipo :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/privoxy force-reload && /etc/init.d/polipo restart
```

You should now be able to connect.

---

Apparently, this problem happens when you have either :

1) Multiple version of Tor (then keep only one)

2) Tor and Vidalia running together

For the n°2, Tor was probably installed before Vidalia, and the automatically starts with the computer. If you would like that tor does not run automatically at startup, run the following command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/tor
```

and change the "yes" to "no" in the following section of this file :

> RUN_DAEMON="yes"

---

For further informations, read :

- http://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tor/+question/94995
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ubuntu-tor-exited-why-not-fixed-in-vidalia-package-891186/
- [How to stop tor from starting before Vidalia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36000/cannot-start-tor-with-vidalia-failed-to-bind-listening-port-because-of-tor-sock)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145092